# mocking ActiveRecord results without stubbing in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec

I'm trying to write specs that test some class calls a method on a bunch of activerecord objects (found by a scope).

This doesn’t work:

```
#someworker_spec.rb
10.times.map { create(:foo) }.each { |f| expect(f).to receive(:bar)
SomeWorker.perform

#someworker.rb
class SomeWorker
    Foo.some_scope.each(&:bar)
end
```

Because activerecord returns new object instances, so the object instance returned by activerecord never receive that method.

I know I can simply stub the `some_scope` method and return doubles with expectations on them, but that seems fragile. I'd rather check that the proper `foo` objects receive that method. Is there a way to make what I'm trying to do above work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with [`and_wrap_original`](http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-4/docs/configuring-responses/wrapping-the-original-implementation)

```
expect(Foo).to receive(:some_scope).and_wrap_original {|relation| 
  relation.call.each {|record| expect(record).to receive(:bar)}
}
```

This does change things somewhat in that the call to each in the above is what will cause ActiveRecord to load the relation, instead of the call to each in your perform method. It also makes the scope return an array rather than a relation

Comment: Frederick - the only issue with this is that it doesn't really verify the intended activerecord models receive the method, as my (not working) code does in the question. is the only way to achieve that here just to add an extra line inside the `and_wrap_original` block that has another expectation: `expect(relation.call.map(&:id)).to match_array(factory_created_objects.map(&:id))` ?

Comment: Sure you could do that, but personally I'd just spec the scope separately.